# sh/bash: Find all files in a folder that start with a number followed by a _blank_

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am working on a shell script, and now I came to a point where I need to rename files that start with a number and a *blank* by removing this pattern and moving them to a specific folder that is basically the string between the second and third " - "

```
example :
001 - folder1 - example.doc > /folder1/example.doc 
002 - folder2 - someexample.doc > /folder2/someexample.doc 
003 - folder3 - someotherexample.doc > /folder3/someotherexample.doc
```

I want to do something like

```
find /tmp -name '*.doc' -print | rename .... ...
```

what I do not know is:
- how to tell find that the file starts with a number,
and second
- how to explode the name by a pattern like " - " and tell rename to place the file in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is very close to the suggestion made by Raman, I removed printf, added the part that creates the folder and added the part removing the leading and the trailing blank.

in the end it looks like this:

```
find . -regex '^.*[0-9].*\.doc$' | awk -F- '{ print "mkdir \""gensub(" $","","g",gensub("^ ","","g",$2))"\" \nmv \""$f"\" \"./"gensub(" $","","g",gensub("^ ","","g",$2))"/"gensub(" $","","g",gensub("^ ","","g",$2"-"$3))"\"" }'|sh
```

thank you everybody for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

If possible, I would avoid `find` and just use `bash`'s regular expression matching. If you don't need to recursively search `/tmp` (as your version of `find` is doing), this should work in any version of `bash`:

```
regex='^[[:digit:]]+ - (.+) - (.+)$'
for f in /tmp/*.doc; do
    [[ $f =~ /tmp/$regex ]] || continue
    mv -- "$f" "/${BASH_REMATCH[1]/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

If you *do* need to recursively search, and you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can use the `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
regex='^[[:digit:]]+ - (.+) - (.+)$'
for f in /tmp/**/*.doc; do
    b=$(basename "$f")
    [[ $b =~ $regex ]] || continue
    mv -- "$f" "/${BASH_REMATCH[1]/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If your destination folder and file names have no spaces, and if all your original files are in the current directory, you could try something like:

```
while read f; do
    if [[ "$f" =~ ^\./[0-9]+\ -\ ([^\ ]+)\ -\ (.+\.doc)$ ]]; then
        mkdir -p "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[0-9]*.doc')
```

**Explanations**:

- `find . -maxdepth 1...` restricts the search to the current directory.
- `find...-name '[0-9]*.doc` matches only files which names start with at least one digit and end with `.doc`.
- The regular expression models your original file names (with the initial `./` that `find` adds). It contains two sub-expressions enclosed in `(...)` corresponding to the folder name and to the destination file name. These sub-expressions are stored by bash in the `BASH_REMATCH` array if there is a match, at positions 1 and 2, respectively.
- The regular expression removes leading and trailing spaces from the destination folder name and the leading spaces from the destination file name (I assume this is what you want).

Comment: I get a failure saying that it reached end of file looking for `"'

Comment: it looks like it comes from   `mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"`

Comment: @eichertc Strange. Can you show the output of `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[0-9]*.doc'`?

Answer (score 1):

With gawk:

```
find . -regex '^.*[0-9]+ - [a-zA-Z]+[0-9] - [a-zA-Z]+\.doc$' -printf %f | awk -F- '{ print "mv \""$0"\" /"gensub(" ","","g",$2)"/"gensub(" ","","g",$3) }'
```

Use find with regular expressions and then parse the output through to awk to execute the move command.

When you have verified that the commands are OK, run the commands with.

```
find . -regex '^.*[0-9]+ - [a-zA-Z]+[0-9] - [a-zA-Z]+\.doc$' -printf %f | awk -F- '{ print "mv \""$0"\" /"gensub(" ","","g",$2)"/"gensub(" ","","g",$3) }' | sh
```

Be wary that such a strategy can be open to a risk of command injection.